# UFT script execution in chrome browser

Tags: hp-uft

Objects are identifying in google chrome browser in UFT v.14. But script is not running when I keep this for run. After some time of execution, it will be object identification error.
Desperately I need help on this.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons which produces object identification issue while using UFT.
Please check below pre-requisites to run your test on Cheome using UFT.

1. Load Web Add-in while launching UFT
2. HP Unified function testing agent should be enabled in the browser.
   For this- Go to chrome://extensions/ and enable the HP UFT Agent extension .
3. Close the browser and try again.